# Android CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS not working?

Tags: android, android-camera2

Can someone explain how LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS works?

the documentation says:

> List of focal lengths for android.lens.focalLength that are supported by this camera device.

> If optical zoom is not supported, this list will only contain a single value corresponding to the fixed focal length of the device. Otherwise, this list will include every focal length supported by the camera device, in ascending order.
>
> Units: Millimeters

The last line says that the output should be a float of my phone's camera focal length measured in mm, but instead the console prints the first value as:

> D/Focal length: 3.95

Which is less than the phone's focal length displayed by the manufacturer:

Motorola Moto G6 Specifications.

> Aperture  f/1.8.

> Focal Length  29mm.

Am I doing something wrong? *I'm using CameraCharacteristics.get(..)* to retrieve that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved. I'm answering my own question in case anyone gets lost as I did.

The thing here is that CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS returns the true focal length of your camera, the tiny lenses of a mobile phone have a focal length of a few milimeters, but that's not what you see when taking a picture.

The key here is to get the **Effective Focal length** which is obtained by multiplying the physical FL by the sensor size. The latter can be obtained using:

> CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE

And taking the Hypotenuse of those values

So you expect the effective focal length of your phone to be:

> EFL = FL * SIZE

Now I get a more reliable value for the focal length of 25 mm

(More Info at [Anton Gorlin Photography](https://antongorlin.com/blog/effective-focal-length-calculator/)

Comment: Could you provide the formula? I've tried: focal_length * (sqrt((sensor_width * sensor_width) + (sensor_height * sensor_height))

Comment: What you have is right, in the Anton Gorlin Photography page is the same expression you wrote

Comment: The formula makes sense, but seems may not be realizable for all device models, as I don't get reliable values as you do.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this and your answer was very helpful. However, I'd like to add a small correction, the formula is actually:

> EFL = FL x CF

CF = Crop Factor, and it's actually not the size of the sensor, but the ratio between 43.27 and the size of the sensor:

> The crop factor is the ratio on the full-frame diagonal to the diagonal of the sensor we calculate.
> Source: [Anton Gorlin Photography](https://antongorlin.com/blog/effective-focal-length-calculator/)

In that case, the final formula is:

> EFL = FL * (43.27 / SIZE)

FL = the focal length returned by LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS

SIZE = sqrt(sensorWidth * sensorWidth + sensorHeight * sensorHeight)

and you can obtain the sensor's width and height using SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE as you said.

I hope this helps